# WCF metadata call not working

Tags: c#, wcf

I have my WCF published in localhost with windows authentication. And i am using wcftestclient for testing.

I am trying to get the metadata. No matter how i try to browse to tools.svc/$metadata, i am getting bad request error.

Below is my web.config.

```
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="defaultBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="mexBehaviour">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="MyBasicHttpBindingSoap" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="mexBehaviour" name="Tools_ws.Tools_Service">
    <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MyBasicHttpBindingSoap"
      name="ToolsServiceEndPoint" contract="Tools_ws.ITools_ws" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>
</services>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

And the error message is

Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from /Tools.svc/$metadata If this is a Windows (R) Communication Foundation service to which you have access, please check that you have enabled metadata publishing at the specified address. For help enabling metadata publishing, please refer to the MSDN documentation at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=65455.WS-Metadata Exchange Error URI: /Tools.svc/$metadata Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: '/Tools.svc/$metadata'. The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate,NTLM'. The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.HTTP GET Error URI: /Tools.svc/$metadata There was an error downloading '/Tools.svc/$metadata'. The request failed with HTTP status 400: Bad Request.

I referred to the microsoft link and many other links in google but not able to make this work. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: are you trying to get OData metadata? or just the wsdl?

Comment: trying to get OData metadata

Comment: Haven't used WCF in a little while, but the basicHttpBinding with mex endpoint behavior doesn't seem correct for OData support. Isn't there another 'web' something binding that supports OData? (Sorry, using WebAPI myself to do OData, not WCF)

Comment: WebHttpBinding (and more) See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412204.aspx